# CommonDbcpNativeJdbcExtractor replacement in spring 5.0

Tags: spring, datasource, apache-commons-dbcp

CommonDbcpNativeJdbcExtractor class is removed from spring 5.0 what is the replacement for getting connection from SimpleNativeJdbcExtractor

Comment: None. What is your use-case. if you can explain, people may provide alternative solution

Comment: Sorry the class was CommonDbcpNativeJdbcExtractor